# Make MPMoviePlayerController main view

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have got a horizontal scrollview like the Springboard with 16 buttons on each of these pages. When you click a button I want to only see the MPMoviePlayerController which plays a video and nothing else, like if you are watching a movie in the videos application. Therefore, I've got the following code:

```
- (void)button: (id) sender {
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"MOV"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    [moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}
```

Unfortunately, I only get to hear sound and there is no video showing. Can anybody help me, please?

**Update:** I found out that you would have to make a frame. I used the following code:

```
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004)];
```

But it isn't in fullscreen that way. Even if I've set the fullscreen property to YES. I can see that because there are no video-controls at the top of the view but at the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You should use the following code:

```
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"MOV"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

[self presentModalViewController:playerView animated:YES];
```